# Can MAGMA tell me the explicit matrices that define a module it computed?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, magma-cas

I have been using MAGMA to compute the radical layers of the indecomposable projective modules of $G=F_8$ (Frobenius group of order $56$) in characteristic $2$ (note that MAGMA automatically extends the field to include the necessary roots of unit, here the $7$-roots). I ran the following code

```
G:= Group("F8");
k:= FiniteField(2,1);
B:=BasicAlgebraOfGroupAlgebra(G,k);
M:=ProjectiveModule(B,1);
IsomorphismTypesOfRadicalLayers(M);
```

and I got the following result

```
Basic algebra of dimension 56 over GF(2^3)
Number of projective modules: 7
Number of generators: 28
[
    [ 1 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 2, 3, 7 ],
    [ 1 ]
]
```

The other six indecomposable projective modules look the same, just permuting the numbers in a specific way. 
I was trying to "guess" how this module (or some submodules of it, I tried $2$-dimensional) is explicitely defined, in other words what matrices express the actions of the generators of $G$ on the vector space... with no luck. 

So I was wondering if there is any way of making MAGMA tell me the explicit matrices that define the projective module. I tried to look it up in the documentation but I was unable to find it.

Comment: Try ActionGenerators(M);

Comment: Sadly this gives me $28$ matrices, because it is viewing the module $M$ as a module on the basic algebra and apparently it has "forgotten" about the group